# How to speed up Video Recording with Python cv2.VideoWriter on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, opencv, video-recording, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to do video recording on Jetson Nano. I found that when the `cv2.VideoWriter` using `write()` the program becomes slow. How can I speed up the `cv2.VideoWriter`? Maybe use `Gstreamer` or `GPU` or `nvidia-component` can speed up the FPS.

My Code:

```py
import os
import time
import cv2

width = 2560
height = 1440
framerate = 30
video_path = 'fps_test.mp4'

gs_pipeline = f"v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 " \
              f"! image/jpeg, width={width}, height={height}, framerate={framerate}/1, format=MJPG " \
              f"! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 " \
              f"! nvvidconv flip-method=4  " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=BGRx " \
              f"! videoconvert " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=BGR " \
              f"! appsink drop=1"

gs_pipeline = gs_pipeline
print(f"gst-launch-1.0 {gs_pipeline}\n")

v_cap = v_writer = None


def main():
    global v_cap, v_writer
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    v_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(video_path, codec, 20, (width, height))
    v_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gs_pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

    prev_frame_fetched_time = 0
    while v_cap.isOpened():
        ret_val, frame = v_cap.read()
        if not ret_val:
            break

        v_writer.write(frame)

        curr_frame_fetched_time = time.time()
        curr_fps = 1 / (curr_frame_fetched_time - prev_frame_fetched_time)
        prev_frame_fetched_time = curr_frame_fetched_time

        print(f"FPS = {curr_fps:.3f}")

    v_cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  # If CTRL+C is pressed, exit cleanly:
        pass
    finally:
        v_cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        if os.path.exists(video_path):
            os.remove(video_path)
```

Console:

```
FPS = 0.000
FPS = 2.438
FPS = 3.606
FPS = 2.805
FPS = 2.741
FPS = 3.265
FPS = 3.603
FPS = 3.524
FPS = 3.290
```

Answer (score 1):

You may first try a pure gstreamer recording with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ev v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 ! image/jpeg, width={width}, height={height}, framerate={framerate}/1, format=MJPG ! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location={video_path}
```

If this works, you may try to split into opencv VideoCapture and VideoWriter, assuming you're processing BGR frames:

```
v_cap_str = f"v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 " \
            f"! image/jpeg, width={width}, height={height}, framerate={framerate}/1, format=MJPG " \
            f"! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 " \
            f"! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx " \
            f"! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR " \
            f"! queue ! appsink drop=1 "
v_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(v_cap_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

and VideoWriter:

```
v_wrt_str = f"appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! queue " \
            f"! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx " \        
            f"! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=NV12 " \
            f"! nvv4l2h264enc " \
            f"! h264parse " \
            f"! qtmux " \
            f"! filesink location={video_path}"
v_wrt = cv2.VideoWriter(v_wrt_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, {framerate as float}, ({width as int}, {height as int}))
```

Check that both capture and writer are opened, then in loop read frames from capture and push these into writer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to potentially speed up the video recording with cv2.VideoWriter is to use hardware acceleration through the NVIDIA Video Codec SDK. You can try using the nvv4l2h264enc GStreamer element with OpenCV's cv2.VideoWriter to encode the video in H.264 format using the hardware encoder on the Jetson Nano.

```
import os
import time
import cv2

width = 2560
height = 1440
framerate = 30
video_path = 'fps_test.mp4'

gs_pipeline = f"v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 " \
              f"! image/jpeg, width={width}, height={height}, framerate={framerate}/1, format=MJPG " \
              f"! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 " \
              f"! nvvidconv flip-method=4  " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=BGRx " \
              f"! videoconvert " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=BGR " \
              f"! nvvidconv " \
              f"! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=I420' " \
              f"! nvv4l2h264enc " \
              f"! h264parse " \
              f"! mp4mux " \
              f"! filesink location={video_path}"

print(f"gst-launch-1.0 {gs_pipeline}\n")

v_cap = v_writer = None

def main():
    global v_cap, v_writer
    v_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gs_pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

    while v_cap.isOpened():
        ret_val, frame = v_cap.read()
        if not ret_val:
            break

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    v_cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        v_cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        if os.path.exists(video_path):
            os.remove(video_path)
```

Comment: First, there's a syntax error for the unessary '' for ```video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=I420```.

Comment: And I got an error:
```[ WARN:0] global /home/nvidia/host/build_opencv/nv_opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (711) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: could not link videoconvert0 to nvvconv1, nvvconv1 can't handle caps video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR```

Comment: The quotes for caps having `(memory:NVMM)` are only required in shell commands so that the parenthesis would not be interpreted by the shell. For programmatic pipelines, just write these without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can multi-threading. So one thread for getting camera frames and another one writing the frames. As both the thread will be running independently there should be no lag/slow down.

Comment: do you mean i have to use a queue to store the frame and write it in another thread?

Comment: Yes. Or you could also create a function for writing frames and send frames to the function and make that function run in a separate thread.